# Hide sheets in Numbers?

Tags: numbers

Is there any way to hide sheets in Numbers? (like in Excel) I have tried everything other than delete, since I may need to refer back to them.

Comment: Has there been any resolution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Within `Numbers` there isn't such a function since you can only see one sheet at a time:[image: Numbers 2 sheets]

All the other sheets than the one displayed are hidden.
The function to switch from one sheet to another one is provided by clicking on the wanted one whithin the sheets column.

Comment: I believe you misunderstood the question. In Excel, selecting Format > Sheet gives the option to hide and subsequently unhide any sheet, which causes its tab to disappear - the sheet is still present, but there's nothing on-screen indicating that. OP appears to want a function akin to that, to hide the sheet from appearing in the Sheets selector in Numbers.

Comment: I have this same question: it is a big waste of screen real estate as well as distracting